# Return / assign variable using emit

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have some variables in a file server.js (they change frequently) and I'd like to pass them to client.js when client sends a request (emits validate). The event is emitted but `var obj` on client side never gets updated. I'd appreciate if someone tells me what is a proper way to return / assign variable.

server.js

```
socket.on('validate', function (obj) {
  console.log("Validate");
  obj.id = 1;
});
```

client.js

```
var obj = {id : 0};
socket.emit('validate', [obj]);
console.log(obj.id);
```

Console output:

```
Validate
0 // Should be 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a socket.emit method in server.js and corresponding socket.on method in client.js for them to communicate.

Server.js

```
socket.on('validate', function (obj) {
  console.log("Validate");
  obj.id = 1;
  socket.emit("validateSuccess", obj);
});
```

Client.js

```
var obj = {id : 0};
socket.emit('validate', [obj]);
socket.on("validateSuccess", function(obj) {
  console.log(obj.id);  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there may be a misunderstanding of how sockets work.  On the client you'll need to listen to the server, just like you're doing in the server.

Once the value changes on the server, you'll need to send that to the client by emitting another event, providing the updated object.  Once the client listens for that event, it can then update its own instance of that object.

#### server.js

```
socket.on('validate', function (obj) {
  console.log("Validate");
  obj.id = 1;
  // send the updated obj object because it will go 
  // out of scope at the end of this function
  socket.emit('validate', obj);
});
```

#### client.js

```
var obj = {id : 0};
socket.emit('validate', obj);
socket.on('validate', function(updatedObj) {
  obj.id = updatedObj.id;
  console.log(obj.id);
});
```

Whenever I'm working with sockets, I try to imagine it as a conversation between two people.  A conversation requires two listeners (event handlers) and two talkers (emit calls).